# Understanding const auto pointers

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider:

```
int main()
{
    int * i0 = new int;
    *i0 = 666; // OK

    const int * i1 = new int;
    *i1 = 666; // FAIL due to const

    auto i2 = new int;
    *i2 = 666; // OK

    const auto i3 = new int;
    *i3 = 666; // OK, WHY?

    const auto * i4 = new int;
    *i4 = 666; // FAIL due to const

    return 0;
}
```

Why does case i3 work? I have always thought that in this case `const auto` would be implicitly `const int *` but I guess this is not the case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
const auto i3 = new int;
```

When you do that, the `const` is applied to the pointer, not to the object it points to.

That is equivalent to:

```
int* const i3 = new int;
```

That means,

```
i3 = new int(20);
```

will not work but

```
*i3 = 666;
```

will work.

Comment: Ok, so it's `int * const` here. Right.

Comment: @juzzlin, that's right.

Comment: Would it be safe to say this is similar to doing `typedef int* point; const point ptr = new int; *ptr = 666`?

Comment: @scohe001, yes. That's very apt.